# Error when using a processing in at Raspberry PI

Tags: java, linux, jvm, raspberry-pi, processing

I try to use Raspberry PI.
and installed processing.
but I have a error on the processing console.
Could you give me advice!

#### Environment:

Raspberry PI Type B.
installed Raspbian(Debian).

#### Processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;
println(Serial.list());
```

#### Error message

> Cannot parse error text:Annotation processing got disabled,since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
>
> Annotation processing got disabled,since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
>   /tmp/hello244179——@temp/hello.java:1 error: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be import processing.core.*;
>
> 1problem(1 error)

Comment: Could you post the output of `java -version` when run in a terminal?

Comment: usually processing comes bundled with the correct version of java. However RPi would require java for ARM CPUs, thus the bundled java wouldn't work. And looks like Java version which you have installed on RPi isn't compatible with Processing.